# Google Play Console - Permissions declaration form for Background Location

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, google-play-console-beta

I am struggling with the Google Play Permissions declaration form. I am trying to get the permission for location tracking in background. Below is the image about my form

[image]

Following, I provided every single details of my app to Google. Finally, I got the email from them say:

[image]

If anyone has any ideas about the `${APK_VERSIONS}`, please let me know. I changed the `version code` and `version name` but it has no effect.

### EDIT

Below is the Location access request

[image]

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Can you share more details on the use-case for the location permission requirement? Google believes the location permission is not required for a critical feature of your app.

Comment: @Abhimanyu: thanks for the quick reply, we write the use-case super clear in the description of 'Location access'. Following, the issue is related to `${APK_VERSIONS}`, which is super unclear what is happening :(

Comment: The `${APK_VERSIONS}` seems to be a place holder text in Google Play Console to show your App version which was rejected. It is an issue from Google Play Console end.

Comment: The rejection is due to some other reason. Try to investigate that. Screen shots of the location access request and use case helps us to identify it.

Comment: @Abhimanyu: I updated the screenshot. About the use-case, we use the location to show vehicle on the map, that is. If you have any clues, please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: "Please note that if you Log out of the app, the GPS is no longer tracking.". Can you shed light on this statement? Does this mean once I log out of my account, the location tracking stops or if the app is moved to the background, the location tracking stops?

Comment: @Abhimanyu: I mean when users log out of the account, the location tracking will stop.

Comment: Hi, I also ran into this problem recently. Did you solve it? What needs to be done to get the update approved?

Comment: @droidbaza: I just turn of the Permissions declaration form for submitting the new version. My app will last until the end of March, hope your app is working too

Comment: @LuongTruong how to solved this problem in  app?

Comment: @krishna https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65993015/google-play-says-i-m-requesting-location-permission-i-m-not