# google play says I’m requesting location permission (I’m not)

Tags: java, android, permissions, android-permissions

**(Problem is Solved)**
Hello google are not publishing my app for background location access
currently am using these permissions for the current location only and am not using background location access these are the permissions in the manifest file and my Gradle please advice

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 30


defaultConfig {
    applicationId "*****"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 82
    versionName "26"
    multiDexEnabled true
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "8g"
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
implementation 'com.wunderlist:sliding-layer:1.2.5'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.1.20'
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
implementation 'com.commit451:PhotoView:1.2.4'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
```

After Adding this line not working yet

```
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" 
tools:node="remove"/>

<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" 
tools:node="remove" />

<uses-permission   
android:name="com.google.android.finsky.permission.
BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFER 
RER_SERVICE" tools:node="remove" />
```

and this is the merged manifest file data

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x20000"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />





also this services
<service        
android:name="com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.
jobscheduling.JobInfoSchedulerService"
android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
android:exported="false" />

<receiver
android:name="com.google.android.
datatransport.runtime.scheduling.jobscheduling.
AlarmManagerSchedulerBroadcastReceiver"
android:exported="false" />

<provider   
android:name="androidx.lifecycle.
ProcessLifecycleOwnerInitializer"
android:exported="false"
android:multiprocess="true"
android:authorities="com
.dolifecycle-process" 
/>

<service
android:name="com.google.android.datatransport
.runtime.backends.TransportBackendDiscovery"
android:exported="false">

<meta-data android:name="backend:com.google.android.
datatransport.cct.CctBackendFactory"
android:value="cct" />
</service>


<provider
android:name="com.google.firebase.provider
.FirebaseInitProvider"
android:exported="false"
android:authorities="com.firebaseinitprovider"
android:initOrder="100"
android:directBootAware="true" />

<service
android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement
.AppMeasurementService"


<receiver
android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement
.AppMeasurementReceiver"

android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity"

<receiver
android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.
FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver"
```

but nothing shows that am using background location service so I uploaded the apk to google play service but I got rejected for the same reason, if there is anything else that I can do help me out thanx

google messages
Background location access not declared
We detected that your app contains at least one feature that requests access to the location in the background, however, your permission declaration form did not reflect this. Please log in to your Play Console to resubmit your location declaration form. You may either remove the location in the background from your app or indicate that the usage is in the background.

The solution to the problem is:

1- from your project go to gradle-wrapper.properties and change the distributionUrl to

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip

2- remove any singleton class that access the location check your Application class

3- Show the permission dialog immediately before gitting it

4- add to your manifast file

```
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" 
tools:node="remove" />
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" 
tools:node="remove" />
```

5- change the compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 30 from build.gradle file

Google console

1- remove any old builds on the testing in my case there were old builds running on 28. SDK so remove them

2- from google console click “App Content”. then "App access" then "All or some functionality is restricted" then "manage" and add the access to your app if its needed one

3- go to “App Content” then "Sensitive app permissions" then "Location permissions" and "Location permissions" and select No from "Does your app access location in the background in APKs or app bundles targeting Android 9 (Pie) or older (SDK level 28 or lower)?"

now submit your build it can take time in my case it took 12 days to be on google play thanx

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30546197/115145

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? We have a similar problem!

Comment: @Rem-D check the last edit at the bottom, please under The solution to the problem is

Comment: Yes thank you! This helped greatly. Our test tracks were the cause. We did a 100% rollout of a build targeting api 29 and this fixed the issue. Thank you for the help

Comment: @UOKlast how to remove old builds from testing? I tried to upload a new build to the testing channel to override old build (also disabled testing channel) and copied to the release channel and after one hour update was rejected again.

Comment: @anton yes check if you have build on a beta test or other tests

Comment: @UOKlast did you change the `minSdkVersion` as well?

Answer (score 2):

Either one of these libraries are using it.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.4.0'
```

You can find out by opening `AndroidManifes.xml` and using the "Merged Manifest" tab at the bottom of this editor. Locate the permission and you will be able to see who is including it by selecting it.

BTW you can remove it from your manifest if you don't need it by using:

```
<uses-permission
     android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"
     tools:node="remove" />
```

Comment: i have added the <uses-permission
     android:name="android.permission. ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"
     tools:node="remove" /> but still not i got rejected by google

Comment: where to use Merged Manifest tab.

Comment: As I said, in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file editor. If you open the file, you will find two tabs in the bottom of the editor, one of it being "Merged Manifest".

Comment: @UOKlast if you copy and pasted the `<uses-permission>` tag, do it again, there was an extra space in the permission `name` attribute.

Comment: I used the same permission
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" tools:node="remove" />

and this is what Google sent me 

resubmit your location declaration form. You may either remove location in the background from your app or indicate that the usage is in the background.

Comment: Check the manifest merge to check which permissions are in the final, merged manifest (and optionally who contributed it). You can use the same `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.xxx" tools:node="remove" />` syntax to remove unneeded permissions.

Comment: yes i have used 

 <uses-permission 
 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" 
 tools:node="remove"/>
    
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" 
tools:node="remove" />
    
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE" tools:node="remove" />

to remove the permission un needed and now I only have 
android:name = android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
from om.google.maps:google-maps-services and still not working

Comment: We’ve reviewed your app for compliance with all Location Permissions policy requirements (including use case eligibility), and found the following issues with your app:
Eligibility Issue
Background location access not declared
We detected that your app contains at least one feature that requests access to location in the background, however  your permission declaration form did not reflect this. Please log in to your Play Console to resubmit your location declaration form. You may either remove location in the background from your app or indicate that the usage is in the background.

Comment: Then I would check the following resources from Google to try to identify the reason: https://developer.android.com/training/location/background and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xTVeFJZQ28c

Comment: I would consider the JobScheduler service and pending intents the primary suspects here, by looking at your merged manifest.

Comment: thank you but how can I remove them? am not using them in my App at all

Comment: You can use `tools:node="remove"` to remove the whole element, as seen in the official documentation https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html#node_markers But I would suggest to use the merged manifest information to understand where it comes from, and if it is really the offending service. Also, maybe you can remove the offending library without any side effects. Totally depends on your code and the full analysis will be out of the scope of Stack Overflow, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes permissions can be "brought in" from other libraries (in your dependencies) via the manifest merger.. essentially because a library you are using needs that permission, it gets added automatically.

Try using the "aapt" command line tool to list the permissions requested by your application [see aapt command line description](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/aapt2).

you probably want "aapt2 dump permissions"

then try looking through your app build folder for the merged manifest files to try and find clues as to where it might have come from.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using `implementation "com.mapbox.navigation:android:2.17.0"` library, and this lib was requiring FOREGROUND SERVICE LOCATION permission, that's why, my app was getting rejected from play console. Then I added these two lines below to manifest file.

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"
    tools:node="remove" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_LOCATION"
    tools:node="remove" />
```

Then my app released to the google play store)